# Any different flags when build .so and .a library?

Tags: gcc, makefile

I know the difference between the **shared library** and **static library**. I am trying to find out the different **gcc flags/options** to build them on linux. I have someone's **makefile** which creates a **.so** file. I just changed the output file name's extension. Then I get the **static library** file, a **.a** file. I tested it. It worked.

I think it may not be that simple. There may be something else I need to change. I am not only asking for this case. I am asking in general, is there any difference **options/flags** when build **.so** and when build **.a**.

The original command is this:

```
 CFLAGS= $(INCLUDE) $(WARN) -Wall

libMyLibrary.so: MyLibrary.c MyLibrary.h
    $(CC) -fPIC -o $(LIB_SRC_ROOT)/libMyLibrary.so -shared              MyLibrary.c $(CFLAGS)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build a shared library, you need to link with `ld` or your compiler (assuming `gcc` and GNU make are used):

```
gcc -shared -o $@ $(filter %.o,$^)
```

To build a static library use `ar`:

```
ar cr $@ $(filter %.o,$^)
```

In the above `$(filter %.o,$^)`

---

Static libraries are just a bunch of `.o` files in one file. Hence when you build one, you have the original `.o` file and its copy in `.a`. If you don't intend to redistribute `.a` files, you may like GNU ar thin archive feature:

> GNU ar can optionally create a thin archive, which contains a symbol index and references to the original copies of the member files of the archive.  This is useful for building libraries for use within a local build tree, where the relocatable objects are expected to remain available, and copying the contents of each object would only waste time and space.

---

On of the best practices to prevent corrupted builds is to put all compiler options (e.g. `CPPFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`) in a separate `.mk` makefile and linker options (e.g. `LDFLAGS`) in another one. Then have `.o` files depend also on `compiler_flags.mk`; executables, shared libraries and archives depend also on `linker_flags.mk`. So that when compiler or linker flags get updated `make` automatically recompiles and/or relinks the targets, e.g.:

```
xyz.so : x.o y.o z.o linker_flags.mk
    g++ -shared -o $@ ${LDFLAGS} $(filter %.o,$^)

x.o : x.cc compiler_flags.mk
    g++ -c -o $@ ${CPPFLAGS} ${CXXFLAGS} $(filter %.cc,$^)
```

This explains why there are `$(filter ...,$^)` in those rules.